# How to remove prefix from a file path stored in an Ant property? 

Tags: regex, ant

I have a file path such as `/repo/java/projects/myproj` in an Ant property. How can I remove `/repo/java` and store the result `projects/myproj` in another property?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `pathconvert` Ant task may be used with a nested `mapper` to remove the first two directories from a path (or get the first two directories).

## Remove prefix `/repo/java/`

### Match '/' file separator

```
<property name="path" value="/repo/java/projects/myproj"/>

<target name="test1">
  <pathconvert property="path.fragment" pathsep="${line.separator}">
    <propertyresource name="path" />
    <mapper type="regexp"
        from="^/[^/]+/[^/]+/(.*)"
        to="\1"/>
  </pathconvert>
  <echo message="${path.fragment}" />
</target>
```

**Output**

```
test1:
     [echo] projects/myproj

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

### Match platform file separator

```
<property name="path" value="/repo/java/projects/myproj"/>

<target name="test2">
  <pathconvert property="path.fragment" pathsep="${line.separator}">
    <propertyresource name="path" />
    <mapper type="regexp"
        from="^${file.separator}[^${file.separator}]+${file.separator}[^${file.separator}]+${file.separator}(.*)"
        to="\1"/>
  </pathconvert>
  <echo message="${path.fragment}" />
</target>
```

**Output**

```
test2:
     [echo] projects/myproj

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

## Get prefix `/repo/java/`

### Match '/' file separator

```
<property name="path" value="/repo/java/projects/myproj"/>

<target name="test3">
  <pathconvert property="path.fragment" pathsep="${line.separator}">
    <propertyresource name="path" />
    <mapper type="regexp"
        from="^(/[^/]+/[^/]+/).*"
        to="\1"/>
  </pathconvert>
  <echo message="${path.fragment}" />
</target>
```

**Output**

```
test3:
     [echo] /repo/java/

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

### Match platform specific file separator

```
<property name="path" value="/repo/java/projects/myproj"/>

<target name="test4">
  <pathconvert property="path.fragment" pathsep="${line.separator}">
    <propertyresource name="path" />
    <mapper type="regexp"
        from="^(${file.separator}[^${file.separator}]+${file.separator}[^${file.separator}]+${file.separator}).*"
        to="\1"/>
  </pathconvert>
  <echo message="${path.fragment}" />
</target>
```

**Output**

```
test4:
     [echo] /repo/java/

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

Comment: If you have ant contrib look at http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/propertyregex.html